# Native messaging with web content using GeckoView Android

Tags: android, browser, geckoview

I am trying to create a hybrid app using only GeckoView as webview. I am following [this](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/mobile/android/geckoview/consumer/web-extensions.html) link to establish communication between native and HTML/Javascript. I am using Connection-based messaging. So far I am able to receive a message from native and send the message back to the native from background script. But I am not able to do the following :

1. Show the message from background script : I have tried to showthe value from custom event inside background script but its not working. Code is as follows :

   ```
    function eventHandler(element){
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
    element.addEventListener('build', function (e) {
        console.log("Inside event listener");
        element.innerHTML="change";
        let text = document.getElementById("text").innerText;
        console.log("Main js executed :::::"+ text);
    }, false);
   ```

   }
2. I have tried to send the message from Content script but its not working either as I am getting browser is undefined.

   ```
   browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
       function (request, sender){
           console.log("Message received");
       });
   ```

I have tried to to use chrome instead of browser but its giving the same result.
I am using 78.0.20200601093812 version of GeckoView. My manifest for only background script is as follows :

```
{


"manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "messaging",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Example messaging web extension.",
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self';",
  "browser_specific_settings": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "message@example.com"
    }

  },
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["resource://android/assets/www/messaging/main.html"],
      "js": ["messaging.js"]
    }
  ],

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery-3.3.1.min.js","background.js", "main.js"],
    "page": "main.html",
    "persistent": true
  },
  "permissions": [
    "nativeMessaging",
    "geckoViewAddons",
    "nativeMessagingFromContent",
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the HTML code is part of your extension you can use [extension pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/user_interface/Extension_pages). Extension pages have full access to the WebExtension API. All you need to do is load the page using the `web-extension://[UUID]` path, something like this should work

```java
session.loadUri(extension.metaData.baseUrl + "/main.html");
```

where `main.html` is a HTML file inside the extension folder, and `extension` is the extension object you get back from [`installBuiltIn`](https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/javadoc/mozilla-central/org/mozilla/geckoview/WebExtensionController.html#installBuiltIn-java.lang.String-).

Then in the `main.html` add a script like this

```
<script src=main.js></script>
```

and in `main.js` you can connect to the app using the same code that you have in the [guide](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/mobile/android/geckoview/consumer/web-extensions.html):

```
// Establish connection with app
let port = browser.runtime.connectNative("browser");
port.onMessage.addListener(response => {
    // Let's just echo the message back
    port.postMessage(`Received: ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
});
port.postMessage("Hello from WebExtension!");
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've edited my Manifests file please check. I have tried to send received data from background script to content script with this manifest as well but getting error of browser is not defined.

Comment: I see so is `main.html` a page that has something that you want to show to your users? In that case you don't need to use a content script (scripts that run as part of `main.html` will have access to the extension API). The way you want to do this is loading the page from the `moz-extension://` path, you can get the base URI on the java side using `extension.metaData.baseUrl` and then appending `/main.html`. Something like

`session.loadUri(extension.metaData.baseUrl + "/main.html");
`

loading the page that way should give it full extension privileges.

Comment: I have followed your solution and now I am not getting the browser error but I am getting two errors. 1.  [JavaScript Error: "Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”)." and 2. [JavaScript Error: "uncaught exception: Native app not found or this WebExtension does not have permissions."].

Comment: Are you using an inline <script> element? On extension pages you can only use external javascript files, like this:

<script src=script.js></script>

and then put your javascript code in the script.js file (in the same folder as the html).

Comment: I am following external javascript file only